# having an error during database connection... initial connection

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data-mongodb, java-threads, mongo-jdbc-driver

**MongoDB connection creation... If I use hibernate and a jdbc connector it works**
**However it does not work with the regular driver**

com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream

I have tried using a connection string instead of a uri
has not worked too

Servlet that tries to create a connection to the database
if it works I need to place it within a class from where I can call it any time

```
import java.io.IOException;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import javax.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import com.mongodb.client.MongoDatabase;
import com.mongodb.MongoClientURI;
import com.mongodb.MongoClient; 
import com.mongodb.MongoClientOptions;
/**
 *
 * @author Tariana
 */
public class MongoTrial extends HttpServlet {

    @Override
    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
         MongoClientOptions.Builder builder = new MongoClientOptions.Builder();
        //build the connection options  
        builder.maxConnectionIdleTime(60000);//set the max wait time in (ms)
        MongoClientOptions opts = builder.build();

        MongoClientURI uri = new MongoClientURI(
            "mongodb+srv://vERC254:%40Steniverse31@cluster0-lyc5i.azure.mongodb.net/test?retryWrites=true&w=majority");

        MongoClient mongoClient = new MongoClient(uri);
        MongoDatabase database = mongoClient.getDatabase("test");
    }


    @Override
    public String getServletInfo() {
        return "Short description";
    }// </editor-fold>

}
```

my pom.xml dependencies

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
        <artifactId>mongodb-driver-legacy</artifactId>
        <version>3.10.2</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
      <artifactId>mongodb-driver</artifactId>
      <version>3.11.0-beta3</version>
    </dependency>
```

here is my error

```
com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:570)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:441)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18-Jul-2019 17:30:43.341 INFO [cluster-ClusterId{value='5d308291cba7207e0ad26cf2', description='null'}-cluster0-shard-00-00-lyc5i.azure.mongodb.net:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger.log Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-00-lyc5i.azure.mongodb.net:27017
 com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:570)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:441)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)

18-Jul-2019 17:30:43.341 INFO [cluster-ClusterId{value='5d308291cba7207e0ad26cf2', description='null'}-cluster0-shard-00-01-lyc5i.azure.mongodb.net:27017] com.mongodb.diagnostics.logging.JULLogger.log Exception in monitor thread while connecting to server cluster0-shard-00-01-lyc5i.azure.mongodb.net:27017
 com.mongodb.MongoSocketReadException: Prematurely reached end of stream
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.SocketStream.read(SocketStream.java:112)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveResponseBuffers(InternalStreamConnection.java:570)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveMessage(InternalStreamConnection.java:441)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.receiveCommandMessageResponse(InternalStreamConnection.java:295)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.sendAndReceive(InternalStreamConnection.java:255)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.sendAndReceive(CommandHelper.java:83)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.CommandHelper.executeCommand(CommandHelper.java:33)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initializeConnectionDescription(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:105)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.initialize(InternalStreamConnectionInitializer.java:62)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.InternalStreamConnection.open(InternalStreamConnection.java:127)
    at com.mongodb.internal.connection.DefaultServerMonitor$ServerMonitorRunnable.run(DefaultServerMonitor.java:117)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
```

but I did not modify the driver file
thread.java

```
 public void run() {
        if (target != null) {
            //the line with the issue but I do not have any issue with it
            target.run();
        }
    }
```

I expect no error on my console